# Liquid: check if object contains certain string

Tags: shopify, liquid

In a shopify template, I create a link with

```
<a href="{{ featured.url | within: collection }}" class="grid-link-slider">
```

I need to check if the url contains a certain word "postcard", and if true, set a second class. Unfortunately,

```
<a href="{{ featured.url | within: collection }}" class="grid-link-slider {% if {{ featured.url | within: collection }} contains "postcard" %}grid-link-postcard{% endif %}">
```

is not working, "contains" can only be used for strings and also the syntax for sure is invalid.
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would capture it like so:

```
{% capture featured_url %}{{ featured.url | within: collection }}{% endcapture %}
<a href="{{ featured_url }}" class="grid-link-slider {% if featured_url contains "postcard" %}grid-link-postcard{% endif %}">
```

Comment: Thank you koosa! That's it!